# pipeline scm library issue

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am struggling with loading a gitlab pipeline library.

here is my configuration :

```
 myLib = library (identifier: 'app@master', retriever: modernSCM(
            [$class: 'GitSCM',
             branches:[[name: "master"]],
             remote: 'https://my-url.com/git/orga/Jenkins-libs.git',
             credentialsId: 'aaaaaaa-8f3f-4e3c-8ade-6c77351e7872',
             includes: '*'
             ])
    )
```

The master branch exists, but Jenkins keeps doing NPE all the time :

```
Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
Getting remote branches...
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/test
Seen 2 remote branches
Checking branch test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.getPattern(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:439)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.isExcluded(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:428)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:306)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:371)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.retrieve(SCMSource.java:616)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:598)
```

Anyone having a clue on the issue ?
Jenkins used : 2.7.4

Regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

have found myself the issue : i had to define the 'excludes' parameter, with a dumb value, otherwise its NPE. Jenkins 2.7.4 doesn't to use this code version : https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/769e7ed3e3971ac4b7c25de60decfbc9f1ea6945/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/AbstractGitSCMSource.java#L204